# How to add static block for Specific category's products in Magento 2 by XML layout

Tags: magento-2.1, magento2.2

I want add a Static block in product details page only for specific category how it will be achieved by XML layout ?

Comment: I want to show the block in product page for a specific category not to all categories. Hope it make sense.

Comment: Did you see the name of layout example? it is catalog_category_view_id_12.xml where 12 number is category id you can replace with your category Id so this block will display only for this category. Make sense now? :) @Vinit

Comment: Thanks for reply ,Yes and it works for category list page but my question i want to show a static block contents to product details page with specific category @KeyurShah

Comment: I am sorry It was my bad :) I misunderstood your question. As per I know I don't think it is possible by XML layout but you can achieve it from backend of the product but it seems length task for you  @Vinit

Answer (score 3):

- Logged in to your backend and open that particular category where you
  would like to call that static block
- Click on Design tab of the category -> Find the Layout Update Xml -> Put below code in that. It will called contact-us-info block on that particular category.

```
 <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="test">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">contact-us-info</argument>
    </arguments>
</block>
```

- Same way You can call your static block from there.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @ Manthan Dave Yes
i did this and it is working the static block contents  are showing on the product details page but i want to add this static block only for the specific category's products  i have  four categories with ids ( 10,11,12,13) i only want to display  the static block for the products of category  (id 12)  not with others category's products  . it it possible to manage by xml can i add condition xml

Comment: Yes Thats what i am saying - Edit your category which have id 12 from backend and put this code in layout update xml file - So block will only display on that particular category. you don't need to write condition for that

Comment: I want to show the block in product page for a specific category not to all categories. Hope it make sense.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can achieve by this XML layout. for this you just need to create `catalog_category_view_id_[ID].xml` where [ID] is your category id. As per the comment, you need to display some static block in `12` number of category then you just need to create a layout `XML` file with `catalog_category_view_id_12.xml` in `your theme > Magento_Catalog > layout` directory and post below content to display CMS static block

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="test">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">YOUR_CMS_BLOCK_IDENTIFIER</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

here I used `<referenceContainer name="content">` you can use what you fell like it.

Comment: I want to show the block in product page for a specific category not to all categories. Hope it make sense.

Comment: Did you see the name of layout example? it is `catalog_category_view_id_12.xml` where 12 number is category id you can replace with your category Id so this block will display only for this category. Make sense now? :) @VinitKumar

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple. You should create `catalog_product_view_attribute_set_id_[ID].xml` where [ID] is your category id. And simply add your Static block inside this layout. The block will be displayed on the product details page for specific category.